# how to execute an for loop till the queue is emptyin c++

Tags: c++, string, stl, loops, queue

i need to execute an for loop till the queue is empty 
my code

```
queue<string> q;
for(int i=0;i<q.size(),i++)
{
     // some operation goes here
     // some datas are added to queue
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
while (!q.empty())
{
    std::string str = q.front();

    // TODO: do something with str.

    q.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the same code as the best answer, but using `for` loop. It looks cleaner for me.

```
for (; !q.empty(); q.pop())
{
    auto& str = q.front();

    // TODO: do something with str.
}
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: for loop doesn't need to instance/initiate a variable, so we just use ';' to tell it do nothing, the condition of the for is until the queue is not empty, at the end of the loop; pop the item from the queue

Comment: Why we need the `&` here?

Comment: It's kind of optimisation. `std::queue::front()` returns a reference to the element that's why there's `&`. We usually don't need an object copy, we can manipulate the string in-place, as we're popping it out later.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a while loop as:

```
while (!q.empty()) {
 // do operations.
}
```

But if you do this immediately after declaring the queue you'll not get in the loop as the queue will be empty on creation. In that case you can use a do-while loop as:

```
queue<string> q;
do {
// enqueue and dequeue here.
}while (!q.empty());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( ! q.empty() )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

```
int size=q.size();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    std::cout<<"\nCell - "<< q.front();
    q.pop();
}
```

But people mostly avoid using for loop because, every time size of queue will be checked against loop counter, where in the middle of n/2 elemets pop up iteration will end up ubruptly as size will become n/2 and i is also n/2. Example mentioned below.

```
for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++){
    std::cout<<"\nCell - "<< q.front();
    std::cout<<"\tSize: - "<< q.size()<<" I value:"<<i;
    q.pop();
}
```